How can i install aihwkit, torch and torchvision and build a cnn
When I tried installing aihwkit with different versions of python i'm getting these errors I'm stuck.
when all the libraries like torch, torchvision, aihwkit got installed i'm getting _lzma not found even if i installed it via sudo apt install lzma. and if trying with another version it is showing aihwkit needs torch 2.0.1 but torchvision needs torch 2.3. and if I finally tried with python 3.7.17 and i got like this
Building wheels for collected packages: aihwkit
  Building wheel for aihwkit (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [123 lines of output]
      
      
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Trying 'Ninja' generator
      --------------------------------
      ---------------------------
      ----------------------
      -----------------
      ------------
      -------
      --
      CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
        Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
        CMake.
      
        Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
        CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
      
      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      
      CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      --
      -------
      ------------
      -----------------
      ----------------------
      ---------------------------
      --------------------------------
      -- Trying 'Ninja' generator - failure
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      
      
      
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Trying 'Unix Makefiles' generator
      --------------------------------
      ---------------------------
      ----------------------
      -----------------
      ------------
      -------
      --
      CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
        Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
        CMake.
      
        Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
        CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
      
      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      
      -- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      -- Configuring done (0.2s)
      -- Generating done (0.0s)
      -- Build files have been written to: /tmp/pip-install-go27xl2v/aihwkit_2c3f10cd94344f3689e0662008f27eb5/_cmake_test_compile/build
      --
      -------
      ------------
      -----------------
      ----------------------
      ---------------------------
      --------------------------------
      -- Trying 'Unix Makefiles' generator - success
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      
      Configuring Project
        Working directory:
          /tmp/pip-install-go27xl2v/aihwkit_2c3f10cd94344f3689e0662008f27eb5/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.7/cmake-build
        Command:
          /home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/shims/cmake /tmp/pip-install-go27xl2v/aihwkit_2c3f10cd94344f3689e0662008f27eb5 -G 'Unix Makefiles' --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/tmp/pip-install-go27xl2v/aihwkit_2c3f10cd94344f3689e0662008f27eb5/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.7/cmake-install -DPYTHON_VERSION_STRING:STRING=3.7.17 -DSKBUILD:INTERNAL=TRUE -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skbuild/resources/cmake -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/envs/env/bin/python -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/include/python3.7m -DPYTHON_LIBRARY:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/lib/libpython3.7m.so -DPython_EXECUTABLE:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/envs/env/bin/python -DPython_ROOT_DIR:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/envs/env -DPython_FIND_REGISTRY:STRING=NEVER -DPython_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/include/python3.7m -DPython_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -DPython3_EXECUTABLE:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/envs/env/bin/python -DPython3_ROOT_DIR:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/envs/env -DPython3_FIND_REGISTRY:STRING=NEVER -DPython3_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/include/python3.7m -DPython3_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release
      
      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      -- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
      -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      -- Invoking cmake through scikit-build
      -- The BLAS backend of choice:OpenBLAS
      -- Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
      -- Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
      CMake Error at cmake/Modules/FindOpenBLAS.cmake:89 (MESSAGE):
        Could not find OpenBLAS
      Call Stack (most recent call first):
        cmake/dependencies.cmake:56 (find_package)
        CMakeLists.txt:39 (include)
      
      
      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 671, in setup
          languages=cmake_languages,
        File "/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 357, in configure
          raise SKBuildError(msg)
      
      An error occurred while configuring with CMake.
        Command:
          /home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/shims/cmake /tmp/pip-install-go27xl2v/aihwkit_2c3f10cd94344f3689e0662008f27eb5 -G 'Unix Makefiles' --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/tmp/pip-install-go27xl2v/aihwkit_2c3f10cd94344f3689e0662008f27eb5/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.7/cmake-install -DPYTHON_VERSION_STRING:STRING=3.7.17 -DSKBUILD:INTERNAL=TRUE -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skbuild/resources/cmake -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/envs/env/bin/python -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/include/python3.7m -DPYTHON_LIBRARY:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/lib/libpython3.7m.so -DPython_EXECUTABLE:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/envs/env/bin/python -DPython_ROOT_DIR:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/envs/env -DPython_FIND_REGISTRY:STRING=NEVER -DPython_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/include/python3.7m -DPython_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -DPython3_EXECUTABLE:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/envs/env/bin/python -DPython3_ROOT_DIR:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/envs/env -DPython3_FIND_REGISTRY:STRING=NEVER -DPython3_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/include/python3.7m -DPython3_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=/home/narravenkataraghucharan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release
        Source directory:
          /tmp/pip-install-go27xl2v/aihwkit_2c3f10cd94344f3689e0662008f27eb5
        Working directory:
          /tmp/pip-install-go27xl2v/aihwkit_2c3f10cd94344f3689e0662008f27eb5/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.7/cmake-build
      Please see CMake's output for more information.
      
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for aihwkit
  Running setup.py clean for aihwkit
Failed to build aihwkit
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aihwkit, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

i tried multiple versions of python to install all torch, torchvision and aihwkit. I want proper installation of above and i should able to use all three libraries in my code. I'm trying to build a cnn from aihwkit.
